# SSH X11 forwarding does not work from a CentOS client to Ubuntu server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xorg, x11-forwarding

I already checked the other threads related to this problem but nothing helped. I want to connect from a CentOS client to a Ubuntu/ARMHF server, start an application on the server and see the opening GUI on the client side.

That's what I have:

- on CentOS client I called `xhost +` and `setenforce 0` and connected with `ssh -X` to the server
- on Ubuntu server side in `sshd_config` `X11Forwarding` is set to `yes`, SELinux does not exist

But when I try to start my application, I still get an error message

> `18:11:57: Error: Unable to initialize GTK+, is DISPLAY set properly?`

So...what else could prevent the GUI to be opened on client side?

Comment: *from a CentOS client to a Ubuntu*  or *from Ubuntu to Fedora*? Why the heck `setenforce 0`?

Comment: @Jakuje sorry, from CentOS - I found an other thread that described SELinux as reason for X11 forwarding problems, so I just tried this

Comment: Neither `xhost +` nor `setenforce 0` should be necessary for SSH forwarding. Doing these things just reduces your security for no benefit.

Comment: Do you have a gui running on the server you are sshing to?

Comment: @Kyle H yes, the "server" is a desktop system where no display is connected - that's why I want to pull this application through SSH